# how to create jar from spring boot project , this jar we want to use in another spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

We are planning to create one spring boot project , which we create as jar file , and this jar we will use as dependency for another spring boot application  , point is the first jar must contains the classes we code and its related jar files , is it possible like that ?can any one help us please .

Problem is when i create the jar  , only my classes which i coded are packing into jar , not the dependencies of that app

Comment: Whether it is a spring boot application or not, any java based application can be made as a jar. Run the `gradle fatJar` task. This will create a jar with all the dependencies as well

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`spring-boot-maven-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) or [`spring-boot-gradle-plugin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html) depending on your build system. Purpose of these plugins is exactly your use case.

Spring Guides are great place to start exploring: [Maven Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/), [Gradle Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/).

The only caveat is that you want to exclude tomcat internal container from such shared library:

Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with more beginner friendly info.

Comment: i created a class , in which one method is annotated with @Scheduled , and i added this app generated into another spring boot , but the "@Scheduled" method is not running when i start the spring boot app in which classpath i added the generated jar , what might be the issue ?

Comment: I would suggest to create separate SO question for your new problem. With code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using "maven shade" plugin for creating a Fat jar, also called uber-jar of the parent project, which you want to use in child project. This Fat jar contains the code you have written along with all the dependencies of the project. You can check here for more details : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html. The Fat jar created will be placed in your local repository.

In your child project, you can use parent project as a dependency by specifying following properties:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>parent_project_group_id</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent_project_artifact_id</artifactId>
  <version>parent_project_version</version>
<dependency>
```

Make sure that you build parent project with maven shade plugin and not with spring boot default plugin. Also, use "clean install" as goal while building the parent project.